# Handling unknown byte size when Receiving data in Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

The below code is working from Receiving Data using Socket.

The problem here is the Byte size should be initialize as expected amount otherwise the Data will not have an expected result.

```
try
{
    byte[] byt = new byte[256]; // Byte size should be intialize as expected 
    clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
    clientSocket.Receive(byt);
    String msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byt);
    Console.WriteLine("Message" + msg);
}catch (SocketException e){
    if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut){
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: Timeout");
    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: " + e.ToString());
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());

}
```

So how can I possibly handle an Unknown size of byte when Receiving the Data?

Comment: Well, how do you *think* you'll know when to stop receiving data? Are you trying to read until the end of the stream? Is there some delimiter to show "that's the end of the text data"? We really need to know about the protocol...

Comment: You know ClientSocket.Receive returns an int - the amount of data you received? right

Comment: @JonSkeet - Actually there's no `delimiter to show "that's the end of the text data"` if possible. Let's say if the Server say "hello" then I wanted to receive the exact "hello" without adding any end of string base.

Comment: And the server isn't closing the connection? If so - and assuming this is a TCP socket - how do you know the server isn't going to send more data "real soon now"? Fundamentally, you need to understand that in a streaming protocol, there's no notion of "I've read all the data" within a stream. The options are usually: a) a length prefix; b) an "end of message" marker; c) reaching the actual end of the stream, e.g. because the socket has been closed. Obviously that precludes any further messages being sent on the stream.

Comment: mmm. Then considering the option `B`, How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the sender. You could pass the size of your package in the fist 4 bytes and convert that to an int

For receiving, you could use

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    ClientSocket.Receive(buffer);
    int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
    buffer = new byte[length];
    ClientSocket.Receive(buffer);
```

For sending add the size to the beginning of your package

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length)
```